# Minikube log rotation

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, minikube, log-rotation

I've read kubernetes and minikube docs and **it's not explicit if minikube implementation supports automatically log rotation** (deleting the pod logs periodically) in order to prevent the memory to be overloaded by the logs.

I'm not talking about the various centralized logging stacks used to collect, persist and analyze logs, but the standard pod log management of minikube.

In kubernetes official documentation is specified:

> An important consideration in node-level logging is implementing log rotation, so that logs don’t consume all available storage on the node. Kubernetes currently is not responsible for rotating logs, but rather a deployment tool should set up a solution to address that. For example, in Kubernetes clusters, deployed by the kube-up.sh script, there is a logrotate tool configured to run each hour. You can also set up a container runtime to rotate application’s logs automatically, for example by using Docker’s log-opt. In the kube-up.sh script, the latter approach is used for COS image on GCP, and the former approach is used in any other environment. In both cases, by default rotation is configured to take place when log file exceeds 10MB.

Of course if we're not in GCP and we don't use kube-up.sh to start the cluster (or we don't use Docker as container tool) but we spin up our Cluster with Minikube what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the implementation

> Minikube now uses systemd which has built in log rotation

Refer this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/700#issuecomment-272249692)